# Accessing data in perl after loading yaml file

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, yaml

I have to parse an yaml and process the data in perl.

my yaml file looks like this:

```
route1:
    dst:
       - atl
    src:
       - bos
route2:
    dst:
       - sfo
    src:
       - dal
```

My parsing script looks like this:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use YAML;
    use Data::Dumper;

    open my $fh, '<', 'testcase'
        or die "can't open file';

     my(@routes) = YAML::LoadFile($fh);
     print Dumper(@routes), "\n";
```

The output of this looks as I expect

```
     $VAR1 = {
               'route2' => {
                            'src' => [
                                     'dal'
                                    ],
                            'dst' => [
                                     'sfo'
                                    ]
                            }, 
               'route1' => {
                            'src' => [
                                     'bos'
                                    ],
                            'dst' => [
                                     'atl'
                                    ]
                            }
               };
```

If I understand correctly @routes is an array.
Each element (route1, route2) of this array is an hash.
Each element of this hash is a hash.
And each element of this hash is an array.

Array of hash of hash of array.

How do I loop through to get the elements of @routes. If I loop through @routes, I should be getting route1 and route2. In the real case, I wont know how many "route" are in my array @routes.

Comment: Your array `@routes` contains one element for each *document* in the YAML string. Because your YAML contains only a single document (as do the majority of YAML sources) your array will have only a single element `$routes[0]`. You need to loop over the elements of the hash that this value refers to; here it has keys `route1` and `route2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@routes` is an array. It contains one element, which is a reference to a hash. This hash has two keys (`route1`, `route2`), and each associated value is another reference to a hash. The inner hashes also have two keys each (`src`, `dst`). The associated values are references to arrays, each of which have one element, which is a string.

You don't see the outer array structure in your dump because you effectively passed a list of the contents of `@routes` to `Dumper`, not the array itself. And the array only has one element, so it is as if you did `Dumper($routes[0])`.

The following code is untested but may work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw(LoadFile);

my $routes = LoadFile('testcase');
my $n = keys %{$routes};
print "There are $n routes\n";

for my $k1 (keys %{$routes}) {
    print "$k1 =>\n";
    for my $k2 (keys %{$routes->{$k1}}) {
        print "    $k2 => @{$routes->{$k1}{$k2}}\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making things unnecessarily complicated by storing the return value of `LoadFile` into an array. YAML allows for multiple documents in a single stream, so in theory `LoadFile` could return multiple references. But in fact you have only a single document in your stream, and that is by far the most common way to use YAML

You should assign the result of `LoadFile` to a single scalar, like this. Note that I have also used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) instead of `Data::Dumper`; it's not a core module (so you may have to install it) but I think it's output is much more readable

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML ();

open my $fh, '<', 'testcase.yaml' or die "Can't open YAML file: $!";

my $routes = YAML::LoadFile($fh);

use Data::Dump;
dd $routes;
```

#### output

```perl
{
  route1 => { dst => ["atl"], src => ["bos"] },
  route2 => { dst => ["sfo"], src => ["dal"] },
}
```

Now I think the structure is clear

- `$routes` is a reference to a hash, with keys `route1` and `route2`
- Each value of `%$routes` is another hash refrence, with keys `src` and `dst`
- The values corresponding to `src` and `dst` are references to arrays, each of which contain only a single element -- `atl`, `bos`, `sfo`, or `dal`

So you have a hash of hashes of arrays

There are many ways of handling hashes, and which method you choose depends on what you ant to do with the information, but you can loop over all the route names by writing

```perl
for my $route ( keys %$routes ) {
    print "$route\n";
}
```

#### output

```
route2
route1
```

and you could, say, display the sources and destinations of each route like this

```perl
for my $route ( keys %$routes ) {

    print "$route\n";

    my $sources = $routes->{$route}{src};
    my $destinations = $routes->{$route}{dst};

    print "  Sources:      @$sources\n";
    print "  Destinations: @$destinations\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
route2
  Sources:      dal
  Destinations: sfo

route1
  Sources:      bos
  Destinations: atl
```

Comment: @PerlDuck: I had to correct the OP's assumption that he wanted to loop over the elements of his `@routes` array before I could address how to walk the data structure.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. Thats exactly what I wanted to do. Just shows how much I need to learn to understand the data structures in perl/yaml better.

Comment: @airr: I suggest that you read and absorb the *Perl Data Structures Cookbook* [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html); it covers this sort of thing thoroughly and clearly.